# cannot ssh first vm created by multi vm vagrantfile and vm name net getting set & public network not getting created for second vm

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have written a multi-vm vagrant file, first I am not able to ssh using vagrant ssh dnsmasq to the first vm and for second vm the public network is not getting created i.e. after I ssh to pihole vm, it only had private network.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
PUBLIC_NET_BRIDGE = 'Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #5'
PIHOLE_PUBLIC_IP =  "192.168.0.111"
DNSMASQ_PUBLIC_IP = "192.168.0.121"


Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", mount_options: ["dmode=700,fmode=600"]
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 1
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "off"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "off"]
  end

  config.vm.define "dnsmasq" do |d|
    # d.provider.name = ""
    d.vm.provider :virtualbox do |dvb|
      dvb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "dnsmasq"]
    end
    d.vm.hostname = "dnsmasq"
    d.vm.network "public_network", ip: DNSMASQ_PUBLIC_IP, bridge: PUBLIC_NET_BRIDGE

    d.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      apt-mark hold ubuntu-advantage-tools
      apt-get update
      apt-get upgrade -y
      apt-get install dnsmasq -y
    SHELL

    d.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"

    d.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      systemctl enable consul
      systemctl restart dnsmasq
      systemctl start consul
    SHELL
  end

  config.vm.define "pihole" do |p|
    # p.provider.name = "pihole"
    # p.vm.hostname = "pihole"
    p.vm.provider :pihole do |pvb|
      pvb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "pihole"]
    end
    p.vm.network "public_network", ip: PIHOLE_PUBLIC_IP, auto_config: false, bridge: PUBLIC_NET_BRIDGE
    
    p.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      apt-mark hold ubuntu-advantage-tools
      apt-get update
      apt-get upgrade -y
      apt-get install net-tools dnsutils -y
    SHELL
    end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

auto_config: false, this is the difference between two vm public network configuration [Public Networks](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network) you can configure static IP on public network with two methods; auto_config needs inline provisioning, easy way to do this is just define static IP along with public network